# Duplicate symbols Error for Binary File IOS

Tags: ios

When I use two third party Libraries in an IOS Application. The following error is show linker error in simulator and on device it works fine. Both are third  party frameworks so cannot edit them. (**AdMarvelSDK and SocializeSDK**).

If I remove one Library the code runs fine. I have checked that if for mistakenly I imported a .M file but this is not the issue.

> duplicate symbol _machineName in:
>
> /Users/IOS Apps/iPhone/AdMarvelSDK/libAdMarvelSDK.a(MologiqAttributes.o)
>
> /Users/IOS Apps/iPhone/Socialize.framework/Socialize(STDeviceSettings.o)
> ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Comment: Is `machineName` declared in a header file without `extern` perhaps?

Comment: I have searched the entire project but the is no decleration of  "machineName" it might be place in the .a files.

Comment: Indeed; as you can see they are in the library/framework you mention.  There is nothing you can do about this without modifying one or both of those libraries as they probably don't even need to make it visible.

Comment: And this question should be re-opened as you have now improved it.